# Pre-allocating the String size in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am very well aware on how to pre-allocate Matrix sizes using ones, zeros and cell command but what about a String ?

Suppose I have a Matrix named `data` whose each value is between 1-255 now if i want to print these number's ASCII characters instead of numbers it selves, I'd do that,

```
msg='';

    for i = 1 : length(data)
        msg=horzcat(msg,floor(data(i))); % horzcat doesn't ignore spaces
    end

msg
```

in the above code Matlab is unaware of the size of the `msg` before the loop ends, What i really want to do is to declare the size of the variable `msg` before the loop starts.

How can i do that ?

Comment: A string in Matlab is just a row vector.  Does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `char` to preallocate a string just as you would a matrix (a string is just a char array):

```
msg = char(zeros(100,1));
```

However, this is probably not what you need (I haven't seen anyone preallocate a string for anything). Given that this is what you want to do

> Suppose I have a Matrix named data whose each value is between 1-255 now if i want to print these number's ASCII characters instead of numbers it selves

you can simply do `char(data)` to display the ASCII/Unicode values.

Comment: i tried this but it is padding un-necessary 0s before the string which are displaying as spaces, this is because the loop is not overwriting the original vector values it is padding the message in to that vector

Comment: you said you haven't seen anyone pre-allocating the string neither did i. but Matlab R2011b keep giving me warning to pre-allocate its size. I know it doesn't worth anything but i just want to remove this warning

Comment: @Xufyan As I said, this is probably not what you _need_, but I answered the question you asked, which was: "How to preallocate a string in MATLAB". I don't fully know what you _want_ to do because your code sample wasn't clear, so I went by what you said in text. Did you try doing `char(data)` as I suggested? That's the best explanation for what you're trying to do with `msg` in the `horzcat` line (which is growing the string one char at a time). If you have floating point numbers in `data` and not integers, do `char(floor(data))`.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori if you are rpeallocating for speedup, you may have to start writing to it as a byte array...