# best way to append text often in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am writing a matlab script that eventually outputs hundreads of lines of text to a file.  Right now I just keep appending text like:

```
Output = [];
Output = [Output NewText];
```

but this I think is inefficient as it has to create a new matrix every time.  What would be a better way.

I can't open the file until I am ready to write all of the text, so I can't just keep using fprintf on the output file.

Comment: do you know in advance a bound on the number of 'NewText' entries that will be appended?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pre-allocating the String size in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398529/pre-allocating-the-string-size-in-matlab)

Comment: Hundreds of lines is not many.  Stick with normal appending, until you demonstrate that this is a performance bottleneck to worry about.  When I/O is involved, it's not likely to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not an obvious best answer to this, at least for me.  Some options are:

1. Exactly what you are doing, incrementally appending to a string for each iteration
2. Intelligently growing your accumulation string to reduce the number of reallocations (the core of the @macduff answer)
3. Using a cell array of strings, and intelligently reallocating that.  (I'm pretty sure) that this only forces a reallocation of pointers, not a full reallocation of the string contents.
4. Using some Java magic to handle string accumulation.  The Java library has many useful features (such as a StringBuilder class), but the Matlab-Java interface is slow.
5. Incrementally writing directly to the file (I know that you have removed this from consideration in the question, but it is still a useful baseline.)

My intuition indicates that the performance order would be:

- Best:  (2 or 3)
- Mid:  (4 or 5)
- Worst:  (1)

but it's not obvious.

Fortunately it's easy to test.  An implementation of all 5 options (plus some testing wrappers) is included in the large test block below.  The results on my computer (a pretty good computer with an SSD, results may vary) are below (spaces added to the code output for formatting):

```
-------------Start of file write speed tests.  (nLines = 1)------------
Time for BaseLine operation:                0.001540 sec
Time for AutoAllocate operation:            0.001264 sec
Time for AutoAllocateCell operation:        0.003492 sec
Time for JavaStringBuilder operation:       0.001395 sec
Time for IncrementalWriteToFile operation:  0.001057 sec
-------------Start of file write speed tests.  (nLines = 100)------------
Time for BaseLine operation:                0.011909 sec
Time for AutoAllocate operation:            0.014067 sec
Time for AutoAllocateCell operation:        0.011517 sec
Time for JavaStringBuilder operation:       0.021291 sec
Time for IncrementalWriteToFile operation:  0.016213 sec
-------------Start of file write speed tests.  (nLines = 10000)------------
Time for BaseLine operation:                3.778957 sec
Time for AutoAllocate operation:            1.048480 sec
Time for AutoAllocateCell operation:        0.856269 sec
Time for JavaStringBuilder operation:       1.657038 sec
Time for IncrementalWriteToFile operation:  1.254080 sec
-------------Start of file write speed tests.  (nLines = 100000)------------
Time for BaseLine operation:              358.312820 sec
Time for AutoAllocate operation:           10.349529 sec
Time for AutoAllocateCell operation:        8.539117 sec
Time for JavaStringBuilder operation:      16.520797 sec
Time for IncrementalWriteToFile operation: 12.259307 sec
```

So, if you are using "100's" of lines, it may not matter very much; do whatever works.  If you know performance matters, then I would use the "AutoAllocateCell" option.  It's pretty easy code (see below).  If you do not have enough memory to store the whole file in memory at once, I would use the "AutoAllocateCell" option with a periodic flush to file.

---

Test code:

```
%Setup
cd(tempdir);
createLineLine = @(n, s) sprintf('[%04d]  %s\n', n, s);
createRandomLine = @(n) createLineLine(n, char(randi([65 122],[1, round(rand*100)])));

for nLines = [1 100 10000 100000]        
    fprintf(1, ['-------------Start of file write speed tests.  (nLines = ' num2str(nLines) ')------------\n']);

    %% Baseline -----------------------------
    strName = 'BaseLine';
    rng(28375213)
    tic;

    str = [];
    for ix = 1:nLines;
        str = [str createRandomLine(ix)];
    end

    fid = fopen(['WriteTest_' strName],'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s', str);
    fclose(fid);

    fprintf(1, 'Time for %s operation: %f sec\n', strName, toc);

    %% AutoAllocated string -----------------------------
    strName = 'AutoAllocate';
    rng(28375213)
    tic;

    str = blanks(256);
    ixLastValid = 0;
    for ix = 1:nLines;
        strNewLine = createRandomLine(ix);
        while (ixLastValid+length(strNewLine)) > length(str)
            str(end*2) = ' ';  %Doubles length of string
        end
        str(ixLastValid + (1:length(strNewLine))) = strNewLine;
        ixLastValid = ixLastValid+length(strNewLine);
    end

    fid = fopen(['WriteTest_' strName],'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s', str(1:ixLastValid));
    fclose(fid);

    fprintf(1, 'Time for %s operation: %f sec\n', strName, toc);

    %% AutoAllocated cell array -----------------------------
    strName = 'AutoAllocateCell';
    rng(28375213)
    tic;

    strs = cell(256,1);
    ixLastValid = 0;
    for ix = 1:nLines;
        if ix>length(strs);
            strs{end*2} = {};  %Doubles cell array size;
        end
        strs{ix} = createRandomLine(ix);
        ixLastValid = ixLastValid + 1;
    end

    fid = fopen(['WriteTest_' strName],'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s', strs{1:ixLastValid});
    fclose(fid);

    fprintf(1, 'Time for %s operation: %f sec\n', strName, toc);

    %% Java string builder -----------------------------
    strName = 'JavaStringBuilder';
    rng(28375213)
    tic;

    sBuilder = java.lang.StringBuilder;
    for ix = 1:nLines;
        sBuilder.append(createRandomLine(ix));
    end

    fid = fopen(['WriteTest_' strName],'w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s', char(sBuilder.toString()));
    fclose(fid);

    fprintf(1, 'Time for %s operation: %f sec\n', strName, toc);

    %% Incremental write to file -----------------------------
    strName = 'IncrementalWriteToFile';
    rng(28375213)
    tic;

    fid = fopen(['WriteTest_' strName],'w');
    for ix = 1:nLines;
        fprintf(fid, '%s', createRandomLine(ix));
    end
    fclose(fid);

    fprintf(1, 'Time for %s operation: %f sec\n', strName, toc);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like Oli says in the comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398529/pre-allocating-the-string-size-in-matlab), a character is a row vector, so any technique that works well for row vectors will for strings.  Start out by allocating as much as you think reasonable, like 1000 characters, then if you blow the limit, double the size or choose your own algorithm.

Here's a trite example:

```
testStrings = {['Is this a dagger which I see before me,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['The handle toward my hand? Come, let me clutch thee.' sprintf('\n') ],...
['I have thee not, and yet I see thee still.' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Art thou not, fatal vision, sensible' sprintf('\n') ],...
['To feeling as to sight? or art thou but' sprintf('\n') ],...
['A dagger of the mind, a false creation,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Proceeding from the heat-oppressed brain?' sprintf('\n') ],...
['I see thee yet, in form as palpable' sprintf('\n') ],...
['As this which now I draw.' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Thou marshall''st me the way that I was going;' sprintf('\n') ],...
['And such an instrument I was to use.' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Mine eyes are made the fools o'' the other senses,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Or else worth all the rest; I see thee still,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['And on thy blade and dudgeon gouts of blood,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Which was not so before. There''s no such thing:' sprintf('\n') ],...
['It is the bloody business which informs' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Thus to mine eyes. Now o''er the one halfworld' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Nature seems dead, and wicked dreams abuse' sprintf('\n') ],...
['The curtain''d sleep; witchcraft celebrates' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Pale Hecate''s offerings, and wither''d murder,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Alarum''d by his sentinel, the wolf,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Whose howl''s his watch, thus with his stealthy pace.' sprintf('\n') ],...
['With Tarquin''s ravishing strides, towards his design' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Moves like a ghost. Thou sure and firm-set earth,' sprintf('\n') ],...
['Hear not my steps, which way they walk, for fear' sprintf('\n') ],...
'Thy very stones prate of my whereabout,'};

A = zeros(1,1000);

idx = 1;
for ii=1:length(testStrings)
  str = testStrings{ii};
  N = length(str);
  eIdx = idx+N-1;
  if( eIdx > length(A) )
    A = [ A zeros(1,length(A)*2) ];
  end
  A( idx:(idx+N-1) ) = str;
  idx = idx + N;
end
fprintf('%s',char(A))
```